# How to get the id of MAX() function

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by, max

I have a table with 3 fields: id_order, id_employee, sum_order.
I need to get the max sum_order of each id_employee and get the id_order. I can group by id_employee and Max(sum_order), but how to show the id_order of this max order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use a `keep` clause:

```
select id_employee, max(sum_order),
       max(id_order) keep (dense_rank first order by sum_order desc) as IdAtMaxSum
from table
group by id_employee;
```